# Why do objects in RStudio/R which display as 1 GB in size get saved by RData or RDS file formats at much larger sizes, even at no compression?

Tags: r

I currently have an list object in `RStudio`, which shows up in the Environment listing as `1.2 GB`. However, when I save with the function `saveRDS` with `compress = FALSE`, the size of saved object shows up as nearly 4 GB.

Is the reporting of the size of my list object wrong or is something else happening? I thought that if an object took up a certain space in R, it should save at that same size without compression? I understand there are a few questions on Stackoverflow similar to this, but none seems to explain why it differs even with no compression.

Comment: What does `str(yourlist, 1)` say, i.e., what is stored in that list? Also, are you sure that you have not changed the default to `ascii = TRUE`? Please show the command used for file export.

Comment: I think it may because I have an `lm` regression object inside that carries in things from the global environment. I did not touch ascii. Could this be why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of the size of objects in R is complicated by the need for efficient memory management. Your list may contain elements that are not accounted for while in memory as they may be shared resources, but will need to be included when exported. The help file for `object.size` states that:

> Exactly which parts of the memory allocation should be attributed to
>   which object is not clear-cut. This function merely provides a rough
>   indication: it should be reasonably accurate for atomic vectors, but
>   does not detect if elements of a list are shared, for example.
>   (Sharing amongst elements of a character vector is taken into account,
>   but not that between character vectors in a single object.)